# Liferay freemarker list tag - Velocity counterpart

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, velocity, freemarker

Within my Liferay 6.2 EE Webcontent template i have the following freemarker code:

```
<#list teaserHeader.getSiblings() as teaser_header>
    <#if getterUtil.getBoolean(teaser_header.teaserVisible.getData())>
        <h2 class="section-headline">${teaserHeader.getData()?html}</h2>
            <div class="inner-15">
                <div class="general-wrapper inner-15-content bound" >
                    <#if teaser_header.teaserImage.getData() != "">
                    <div class="product-image-wrapper left">
                        <img src="${teaser_header.teaserImage.getData()}" width="" height=""/>
                    </div>
                    </#if>
                    <div class="product-teaser-info left">${teaser_header.teaserContent.getData()}</div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </#if>
</#list>
```

Unfortunately we have to switch to Velocity.

**What's the best approach to transform freemarkers list tag to Velocity ?**

I already adopted everything else (if tags, method calls, ...)

But i have some troubles with the list tag.

I tried to do it with foreach in Velocity but i failed...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In velocity it should look something like this:

```
#if (!$teaserHeader.getSiblings().isEmpty())
    #foreach ($teaser_header in $teaserHeader.getSiblings())
        ...
    #end
#end
```

Comment: Just a question: why do we have to check if the siblings list is empty? Would it fail to iterate over an empty list?

Comment: no, just a check if there is a teaserheader with a value